# How to get a file from golang echo?

Tags: go, swagger, echo

I'm using golang echo, I'm doing image file transfer with curl like below,

```
        curl -X 'POST' \ 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/file' \ -H 'accept: multipart/form-data' \ -H 'Authorization: 
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjE5LCJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY3Njk1NDc4MH0.-6NjeX_roNcmafxjPDyL_24lGainwkc472l9WS9BNII' \ -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
 \ -F 'files=@\\\\\.PDF;type=application/pdf' \ -F 'files=@1VE5F3W5WP_18.png;type=image/png'
```

If you check the log after coding the transmitted data as below, the value of {[]} is returned. I don't know why the file is not loaded, I need help

```
type SaveFileReq struct {
    Files []*multipart.FileHeader `form:"files"`
}


    var temp req.SaveFileReq
    err := c.Bind(&temp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(temp)
```

output data is = {[]}

How can I receive and control the file?

the code below is the swag doc

```
// @Summary 파일을 저장합니다
// @Description 파일을 저장합니다
// @Tags 파일
// @Accept mpfd
// @Produce json
// @Param files formData []file true "file"
// @Success 200 {object} common.DefaultRes
// @Failure 400 {object} common.DetaultError
// @Security Authorization
// @Router /v1/file [post]
```

Comment: why you only bing `multipart.FileHeader`, there are no filedata?  [how-to-upload-multiple-files](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/file-upload/#how-to-upload-multiple-files-with-parameters)